Display MsgBox if cell value changes and is not blank
I have a range (merged cell) M5:O5 that needs to trigger a MsgBox as follows:

If range is edited and is not null
If range is deleted to a null value then no MsgBox
If range is selected and box is empty or has data then no MsgBox

What I have so far:
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
   Dim billtoanswer As Integer
   'If IsNull(Range("M5:O5")) Then  <-- other stuff I was trying
   'End
       If (Application.Intersect(Range("M5:O5"), Target) Is Nothing) Then
       End If
       billtoanswer = MsgBox("Use this address for Bill To?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Bill To?")
       If billtoanswer = vbYes Then
       Range("F26").Value = Range("M4").Value & ", " & Range("M5").Value
       End If
   End If
End Sub

Microsoft® Excel® for Microsoft 365 MSO (Version 2404 Build 16.0.17531.20190) 64-bit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
   Dim billtoanswer As Integer
   
   If (Application.Intersect(Range("M5:O5"), Target) Is Nothing) Then
      ' Skip
   Else
      If Trim(CStr(Target.Text)) = "" Then
         ' Skip
      Else
         billtoanswer = MsgBox("Use this address for Bill To?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Bill To?")
         If billtoanswer = vbYes Then
            Range("F26").Value = Range("M4").Value & ", " & Range("M5").Value
         End If
      End If
   End If
End Sub


I was so close!!!
But couldn't figure out the determination of if edited to nothing:
If Trim(CStr(Target.Text)) = "" Then
...and there it is!!!
Thank you @Tin Bun

A Worksheet Change: Write to Another Cell

The Worksheet Change event is fired each time you manually enter values i.e. write or paste to the sheet. This includes writing to the sheet (with VBA) while the event code is running.

Application.EnableEvents

To prevent the latter from retriggering the event, it is good practice to disable events before writing to the sheet while the event code is running.
In this case, it is less important since retriggering the event will exit with the line If Intersect... but in a worst-case scenario if you would e.g. write to the target cell (M5) while the event code is running, a repeated firing of the event would crash Excel.

Target

The Target variable is a reference to all cells that have changed. If you're monitoring a single (target) cell for a change, use a variable (targetCell) in the continuation of the code by referencing the intersection of it (a single cell) and Target (need not be a single cell). Use Target only if you have ensured that it is a single cell with e.g. If Target.Cells.CountLarge = 1 Then.


Sheet Module, e.g. Sheet1
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    ChangeBillingAddress Target
End Sub

Standard Module, e.g. Module1, modEvents... (or the Same Sheet Module)
Sub ChangeBillingAddress(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Target.Worksheet

    Dim targetCell As Range: Set targetCell = ws.Range("M5")
    If Intersect(targetCell, Target) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    If Len(CStr(targetCell.Value)) = 0 Then Exit Sub
    
    Dim BillToAnswer As Long
    BillToAnswer = MsgBox("Use this address for Bill To?", _
        vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Bill To?")
    
    If BillToAnswer = vbNo Then Exit Sub
    
    Application.EnableEvents = False ' prevent retriggering the event
        ws.Range("F26").Value = CStr(ws.Range("M4").Value) _
            & ", " & CStr(targetCell.Value)
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub 

